# How to style notification message for pushnotification

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, android-4.4-kitkat

Hi, Tried to override the push notification status. As I am working on cross platform application I felt difficulty to override the native functionality. What I am looking for is based on device OS. I need to show different types of notification.

---

We know that kitkat able to show inboxstyle with summary text but in ics its not posssible. In my app, I am able to show notification in kitkat but in ICS only content title is getting displayed, not message.

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 4.4){
 // Entering into loop if the device is below kitkat version
            if (message != null) {

                mBuilder.setContentTitle(message);
                mBuilder.setContentText(message);
                //mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
            } else {
                mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
            }

        }else{
            if (message != null) {
                inboxStyle.setSummaryText(message);
                inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font weight='bold' color='Red' size='larger'>Alerts</font>"));
                  inboxStyle.addLine(Html.fromHtml("<span style=\"background: red;\"><font weight='bold' color='white' size='large'>"+message+"</font></span>"));

            } else {
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font weight='bold' color='Red' size='larger'>Alerts</font>"));
              inboxStyle.addLine(Html.fromHtml("<p><font weight='bold' color='white' size='small'>missing message content</font></p>"));
            }
             mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        }
```

Can u share some inbox style format? 
Even span background color is also not applying.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use RemoteViews for custom layouts (when you want to play with colours / text size / images etc. Check out this answer : [Change Notification Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout)

Also, to support notification building for various various versions of android. I'd suggest using [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) It'll automatically modify notifications based on the features supported in that particular android version. Check out this answer : [How to create a notification with NotificationCompat.Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902115/how-to-create-a-notification-with-notificationcompat-builder)

Comment: Is this possible for Sencha touch based application? why i am asking i will extend to webview its possible to style the notification bar

Comment: Ideally it should since Native Android provides such an option. But I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your info i will try and let you know.

Comment: Its not working for hybrid mobile application.. i am using Phonegap+Sencha touch. Please let me know if u have any suggestion