# Getting Notification in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have added a some itent like AACTION_POWER_CONNECTED in my manifest file, I want to get Notification when charger is connected. This my code.

```
    public class AwesomeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Inside onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("This is A Notification");
        mBuilder.build();

    }
}
```

I am getting the `Toast` each time when I connect my charger but not getting the notification. As I am completely new in Android, I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Please review your code before you post it on social site. :P

Comment: P.S. I am talking about Message in toast. :D

Comment: You forgot notify notification.

Comment: Use this to show notification. 
`NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());`

Comment: don't use abusive language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a notification with NotificationCompat.Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902115/how-to-create-a-notification-with-notificationcompat-builder)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class AwesomeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Inside onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("This is A Notification");

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Actually you created Notification object but never fired it :)
So, you were simply remaining with the `notify()` to call.

Comment: what id `mId`, here ?

Comment: @Firdoeshkhan Its unique id assigned to every notification. For now, you can pass 0