# What version are the source versions of the system that Android compiled and run on the phone?

Tags: android

For example, I now have a program like Figure 1 (based on Android O):

[image]

Then I tried to write a notification function, and found a NotificationChannel object, but after writing it, like figure two

[image],

when I removed the if, I would make a mistake on the cell phone below Android O, because I couldn't find this class.
Then Android O's notice also added a setTimeoutAfter (2000) method to set the notification disappear delay. This method didn't exist before Android O, but this method didn't add if limit, and it didn't report the error when running on the cell phone below Android O. I want to know why this is? Why does NotificationChannel make a mistake, and setTimeoutAfter doesn't make a mistake.

Or, as the title, Android compiler, I think I was determined with the 26 source code version, then run to each low version of the mobile phone, the mobile phone also should be each own version, I wonder why is setTimeoutAfter this method can perform (and no effect), rather than the exception.

Comment: Your if statement surrounding that code prevents any of it from running... What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: Please don't post images of code; they're useless here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons to avoid doing so. Code is text, and can be easily copied and pasted into your question in that form. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem.

Comment: Your `setTimeoutAfter`  maybe [NotificationCompat.Builder.setTimeoutAfter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setTimeoutAfter(long)).

Comment: you are right ,Toris,why NotificationCompat.Builder.setTimeoutAfter () can be compatible but NotificationChannel can‘t be compatible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know that I can't use  pictures

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder is android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder, and support-v4 is designed to work with API9.

Comment: @Toris，Why it is not wrong to run 'NotificationCompat.Builder.setTimeoutAfter()' in the device under Android O,only No response

Comment: My English is very poor，so....sorry

Comment: When running NotificationCompat.Builder.setTimeoutAfter in a device less than Android O, the source code used is the source code of the current device, such as android-21. When running to setTimeoutAfter, the system will decide if there is no such method, will it skip right?

Comment: 'var mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)',Android-21 does not have this construction method, so what does the system do when it runs to my code?

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder is a builder for NotificationCompat, as name shows, and NotificationCompat is a helper for accessing features in Notification. Notification is from API1, so support library uses such classes, I think. Even if no such class exists, support library uses similar classes or functions.

Answer (score 0):

`compilesdkversion` is a bottom line or more for any classes / functions in source codes, as it is used for compile.

`minSdkVersion` is a bottom line app can be installed to a device.

`targetSdkVersion` is for deciding compatibility behaviors on a device.

`Build.*` are basically run time values on a device.

Classes that have "Compat" in there names are designed to work with older platforms. `NotificationCompat.Builder.setTimeoutAfter()` is one of these.

---

Related articles:

From question [What is the difference between compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion)

- compilesdkversion

  > The compileSdkVersion property specifies the compilation target.

From [Guide - App manifest - uses-sdk](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

- `minSdkVersion`

  > An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute.
- `targetSdkVersion`

  > This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

From [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class reference

- Build

  > Information about the current build, extracted from system properties.

---

Related question for NotificationCompat.Builder:

[How to create a notification with NotificationCompat.Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902115/how-to-create-a-notification-with-notificationcompat-builder)

NB: NotificationCompat.Builder is a class of support-v4 library.
support-v4 library was for devices >= API4, as name shows. (Current document says it's for API9.)