# What is transient notification and persistent notification in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

We are working on custom notifications for our projects and came across about the transient and persistent notifications in Android. I am not able to get really what it is.

Transient notification - Are this type of notifications are like new SMS, new mail or any notification which disappears after reading or clearing the same?

Persistent notification - Will this notifications are permanent notifications in the notification bar? If so how to create persistent notifications?

Please clarify me. Tried googling but didn't got sufficient information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent Notifications are like [onGoing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT) Notifications, like the USB Connection and WiFi Notification. If you want to create a Persistent Notification, have a look at the following Post,

[Create a Persistent Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206585/1626878)