# Android Hide Notification

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I would like to make an Android app that shows an icon in the notification bar, however I don't want an actual notification to appear when you scroll down the bar.

The point is to show info only through a changing icon. 
Is this possible to do, even if it requires some strange workaround? 
I'll be glad if someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: Too bad :-(, thanks anyway. If someone else found a workaround, I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a permanent notice is not removed swipe,
but only in the tray icon - rather impossible.

[Persistent notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205551/create-a-persistent-notification-and-prevent-notification-in-status-bar)

Comment: Thanks, too bad :-(. Is there a different way for sticking such an icon permanently on the screen, maybe not via a notification?