# How to make an Android notification "persistent"?

Tags: android, notifications

On my Android 10 device, I see that the LastPass app is able to create a "Persistent notification". As seen in this screenshot below:

[image]

I have an application which I want to have a persistent notification for running my foreground service. But after all attempts, I don't get the the same observation as the LastPass app with saying its a "persistent notification". It just shows just as a "notification".

Does anyone know how to do this? Does anyone know if it really matters?

Comment: I think You are searching this [Android notification persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206585/9816845)

Answer (score 3):

> On my Android 10 device, I see that the LastPass app is able to create a "Persistent notification". As seen in this screenshot below:

That is not a "persistent" notification - that is a [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels), which LastPass has apparently opted to call "Persistent notifications" for whatever reason.

> I have an application which I want to have a persistent notification for running my foreground service.

Sounds like you want an [*ongoing* notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just make setOngoing true. It will be persistance.

NotificationCompat.
Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
.setOngoing(true)